# How to start and stop Stream using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have implemented a Steaming API for twitter. I get the streams perfectly. However, My program never ends. I have tried many combinations but can't figure out why. I am suing Apache AsyncHttpClient in java. My goal is to start the stream for example for 10 seconds, get the streams, and gracefully close the stream and exit the application (I am expecting this to happen when my Main method ends naturally). This is the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    TwitterStreamingHttpClient client = new TwitterStreamingHttpClient();
    Executor ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ex.execute(client);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    client.ceaseStream();

    LOG.debug("Keeps running");     
}
```

and this:

```
public class TwitterStreamingHttpClient extends DefaultHttpAsyncClient implements Runnable
{
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterStreamingHttpClient.class);
    /**
     * @throws IOReactorException
     */
    public TwitterStreamingHttpClient() throws IOReactorException
    {
        super();
        // TODO: parametrize it, load from config file, spring config file?
        this.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("stream.twitter.com", 80),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        this.start();
    }
    public void initiateStream() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {

        String requestContent = new String();

        requestContent = "track=NothingFeelsBetterThan";
        Future future = this.execute(HttpAsyncMethods.createPost(
                "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json", requestContent,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED), new TwitConsumer(), null);
        Boolean result = future.get();
        if(result==null)
        {
            LOG.error("Requested to close stream!");
            return;
        }
    }
    public void ceaseStream()
    {
        try
        {
            this.shutdown();
            LOG.info("Shutting down the stream");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            LOG.debug("InterruptedException {}", e);
        }
    }
```

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
 */
public void run()
{
    Thread.currentThread().setName("initiateSTream Thread");
    try
    {
        initiateStream();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried to add a return whereever I though it mightbe helpful. but no luck. Can someone help me with this?

**Edit 1:** When I use the debug mode, I can see that the "initiateSTream Thread" thread. is  still running while the main thread is gone!

**Edit 2 (Solution):** In the main method, I replaced:

```
Executor ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ex.execute(client);
```

with:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(client);
thread.start();
```

Now my programs ends after the designated time of streaming. But why? What is the difference between the two approaches?!

Comment: Have you seen this post ?http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/nings-async-http-client-and-twitter-streaming-api/